# How to Boost up the emulator

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio in AMD processor system and the emulator is running very slowly. In the emulator i have allocated RAM size to 1 GB and system image to armeabi-v7a of API-level 23 but still the emulator comes after delay of 10 minutes.please help me in it

Comment: what are you using linux or windows?

Comment: windows @user2704821

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Comment: that question didn't help me @ZeeshanShabbir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I suggest you to use  [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) for Android Studio. Blazing fast! Just needs one time installation. No more AVD pain.

[Features](https://www.genymotion.com/features/)

> System Requirements
>
> Microsoft Windows 7, 8/8.1, 10 (32/64 bit) 64 bit CPU, with VT-x or
>   AMD-V capability, enabled in BIOS settings Recent and dedicated GPU
>   400 MB disk space 2GB RAM

Comment: can i use ADM functions like sending sms, getting .db files to the emulator

Comment: Yes . It provide almost all

Comment: Im using AMD processor system with 3GB RAM and windows OS in this laptop there is SV enabled.

Comment: Great! you can use Genymotion

Comment: thanks @Nirav Ranpara it works but i couldn't able to send a sms to it

Comment: Start to virtual device and test!

Comment: as i run the app emulator its lunched and app gets open all working good but i need to send sms to the device. In Android Device Monitor     Telephony Actions are not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Genymotion**](https://www.genymotion.com/) which runs very smoothly. Also, you can update your Android Studio to latest version, update your gradle version to latest version. Remove all your old emulators and create new emulator which is fast compare to other old emulators.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all emulators like [Xamarin Android Player](https://www.xamarin.com/android-player), [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), [Nox](http://en.bignox.com/), [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/), ... using x86-based system images because they are about 10 times faster than ARM-based system images.

if it's not necessary to use ARM-based system image you can use another emulator like Genymotion or Xamarin Android Player or Nox (I prefer to use Nox) but if you need an ARM-based emulator try enabling Snapshot or Use of host GPU when creating a new Virtual Device to get faster operation.

[image]